# Can I use the pattern matching operator ~= to match an enum value to an enum type with an associated variable?

Tags: swift, enums, pattern-matching

I would like to compare an enum value to an enum type without using switch. The following code, for example, works using the `~=` operator:

```
enum MyEnum {
    case A, B
}

let myEnum = MyEnum.A

let isA = myEnum ~= MyEnum.A
```

`isA` equals `true` above.

However, when I try to compare an enum of an enum type with an associated value, like below, I get the compile error `Binary operator '~=' cannot be applied to two MyEnum operands`.

```
enum MyEnum {
    case A, B(object: Any)
}

let myEnum = MyEnum.A

let isA = myEnum ~= MyEnum.A
```

Is there a way to work around this error to use the `~=` pattern matching operator? Or is my only recourse the following syntax, which in my opinion is significantly more cumbersome:

```
enum MyEnum {
    case A, B(object: Any)
}

let myEnum = MyEnum.A

let isA: Bool
switch myEnum {
case .A:
    isA = true
default:
    isA = false
}
```

Thanks in advance for your input and suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation for Swift 1.2 *"Enumeration case patterns appear only in `switch` statement case labels"*. So yes, you need to define your `~=` operator (as from the answer pointed in the comments).

In case you just need `isA` and `isB` you can implement them using `switch` combined with `_`. In your case `~=` couldn't work *out of the box* anyway, since you use an `Any` associated type, which is not `Equatable` (i.e.: how can I say if two `.B(any)` are equal since I cannot say if two any are equal?)

As an example, here is an implementation of from your code that uses `String` as the associated type. In case you just need the `isA` and `isB`, you can still use `Any` as the associated type without implementing the `~=` operator.

```
enum MyEnum {
    case A, B(object: String)
}

let myEnumA = MyEnum.A
let myEnumB = MyEnum.B(object: "Foo")


func ~=(lhs: MyEnum, rhs: MyEnum) -> Bool {
    switch (lhs, rhs) {
    case (.A, .A):
        return true
    case let (.B(left), .B(right)):
        return left == right
    default:
        return false
    }
}

myEnumA ~= .A   // true
myEnumB ~= .B(object: "Foo") // true
myEnumB ~= .B(object: "Bar") // false

func isA(value: MyEnum) -> Bool {
    switch value {
    case .A:
        return true
    default:
        return false
    }
}

func isB(value: MyEnum) -> Bool {
    switch value {
    case .B(_):     // Ignore the associated value
        return true
    default:
        return false
    }
}
```